# How can I get my node.js unit tests to recognize node_modules?

Tags: unit-testing, node.js, mocha.js

I have the following code:

```
var foo = require('foo'); /* module.exports = function(n){ return 2 * n} */

describe('basic', function(){

 describe('body', function(done){
      foo(2).should.equal(4);

 });
});
```

this is in `[project_root]/tests/foo_test.js`.

`foo.js` is in `[project_root]/node_modules/foo.js`. However when I run `mocha` (visionmedia's test suite) from `[project_root]` `foo_test.js` cannot load `foo.js`. `proces.cwd()` does display [project] as the root of the process.

Why doesn't `foo.js`load in my testing context?

Answer (score 1):

Try to force the module path with NODE_PATH

```
$ export NODE_PATH = [project_root]/node_modules
```